# How to get Particular content from Resume using OpenXML SDK in .net MVC

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk

My requirement is when employee imports resume on screen, automatically Name, experience, email etc.., should fill the text boxes automatically when he is registering time.

For that I am using Open XML SDK 2.0, i have written the code like

```
                using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(path, true))
                {
                    MainDocumentPart mPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;
                    var part = doc.MainDocumentPart;
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(mPart.GetStream()))
                    {
                        XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(XmlReader.Create(reader));
                        XNamespace w = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main";
                        // the elements we will be looking for data.
                        XName rPr = w + "pPr";
                        XName p = w + "p";
                        var query =( from element in xDocument.Descendants(p)
                                    select new DocumentModel
                                    {
                                        ItemProperty = element.Element(rPr) != null ?
                                       ((from sElement in element.Descendants(rPr)
                                         select new ItemProperty
                                         {
                                             Style = sElement.IsEmpty == false ?
                                             (sElement.Element(w + "pStyle") != null ?
                         sElement.Element(w + "pStyle").Attribute(w + "val").Value :
                        string.Empty) : string.Empty,
                                             Lang = sElement.IsEmpty == false ?
                                             (sElement.Element(w + "lang") != null ?
                        (sElement.Element(w + "lang").Value ?? string.Empty) :
                        string.Empty) : string.Empty
                                         }).First<ItemProperty>()) : null,
                                        Text = element.Value == string.Empty ? "<br/>"
                        : element.Value

                                    }).ToList();

                        model.EMP_NAME = query.Text; //Getting Candiate Name here
                    }
                }
```

I Want to get Email, Mobile Number etc.., Result is coming in different parts like a list, Each part contain Name, Email etc.

How can I find this content exactly while executing the above query. Please help me anyone.

Comment: Down voter..!! what is the problem in this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this is vast code, but it helps you, that you can recognize email,name, phone number. You can try in more matured way..!!

```
string[] separators = new string[] { ",",  "!", "\'", " ", "\'s" };
foreach (string word in element.Text.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
  {
     //Split the each work and validate Name , Email, Phone Number.
    bool Name = Regex.IsMatch(word, @"^[\p{L} \.\-]+$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    if (Name)
      {
         if (fileContentModel.FIRST_NAME == null)
           {
              fileContentModel.FIRST_NAME = word;
           }
         else if(fileContentModel.LAST_NAME ==null)
           {
              fileContentModel.LAST_NAME = word;
           }
       }
     bool isEmail = Regex.IsMatch(word, @"\A(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)\Z", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
     if (isEmail)
     {
       fileContentModel.EMAIL = word;
     }
     bool isPhoneNumber = Regex.IsMatch(word, @"(\([2-9]\d\d\)|[2-9]\d\d) ?[-.,]? ?[2-9]\d\d ?[-.,]? ?\d{4}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
     if (isPhoneNumber)
     {
        fileContentModel.PHONE = word;
     }
  }
```